# Django - User Model for Dating site - Admin -Staff/Agency+ other users

Tags: django, model, varying

I'm trying to make my first django app (a dating site) that consist of varying user models.

Users need to have fields like location,language,religion, height, preferences, family details horoscope etc.

Staff/Agency - users added by Admin from the panel - some contact details like address,phone etc would be enough. No self registration required.

I prefer to have email-id as the USERNAME field.

Can someone please guide me how do I proceed to make User models in this case? I have been struggling to follow the docs and various thread on forums to get some light.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you completed the Django tutorial? It is great and is really the entry point to using Django!

Comment: Yes @Tony, I've gone through it and followed almost all pages. I've also created the experimental poll app.

Answer (score 1):

You should 'extend' the django user class by creating a one to one model, generally called a profile that contains the rest of the information you need to gather on a person.
It is considered bad practise and difficult to extend djangos user class directly.
Have a look at this youtube video, it's a bit out of date so don't copy it word for word, but it gets the general concept across.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLRxkStiaUg